# FolderBrowserDialog apears in back in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, folderbrowserdialog

I'm using FolderBrowserDialog on my web application in c#.
It is working perfectly except one issue:

the FolderBrowserDialog open in the back of the web application and not in front of it.

The code is:

```
public void BrowseFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{            
    FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();     
    folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;                       
    DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();                        
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)  
    {                          
        textBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath;                  
        Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderDlg.RootFolder; 
    } 
 }
```

for the second time the user click on the button it opens in the back.
Any help will be appriciate!

thanks,
Moran

Comment: are you calling FolderBrowserDialog on Server side?

Comment: For which purpose do you use `FolderBrowserDialog`? Can you show some code handling its output? Did you try deploying the application to web server and accessing it from separate PC?

Comment: Thanks for the response! i'm calling it on server side. @Vladimir Gondarev

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need the user to choose a folder so he can save a file to this folder. @nrodic

Comment: Are you sure your server has console user? Anyway, I don't think it could be achieved without having winforms application window. Maybe you would like to read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21895/Directory-Browsing-in-ASP-Net-2-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FolderBrowserDialog will always popup at the Server side, the client/browser will never see it so client would hang there forever waiting for input...

In your case, both Client and Server on the same pc, this is why you saw the dialog working.
As far as I know there are no components from Microsoft that allow to browse the Folders on Client side. But you can always try open source Solutions...

for instance:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21895/Directory-Browsing-in-ASP-Net-2-0

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check it. Thank you for the response! @Vladimir Gondarev